# how to run multiple byobu sessions at once?

Tags: byobu

Currently I don't seem able to run multiple sessions of `byobu`. After the initial byobu instance, running on one terminal,  when I run `byobu` in another terminal it always attaches to the first `byobu` session.

Is there away to start independent `byobu` sessions?

Answer (score 73):

It is very easy. (At least on my ubuntu 10.04 machine, where byobu uses screen.);

If you already have one session running, and do not want to reattach but instad create a new one, just type:

```
byobu -S my-other-session
```

Where my-other-session is how you are naming the new session.

Later, if you have already more than one byobu sessions running, it is sufficient to type

```
byobu
```

And you will be presented with a list of running sessions to choose from:

```
Byobu sessions...

  1.  17680.my-other-session (03/12/2012 01:33:32 PM) (Detached)
  2.  11890.pts-2.mit        (01/15/2012 09:17:49 AM) (Detached)
  3.  Create a new session

Choose 1-3 [1]:
```

If typing `byobu` dos not present a list of running sessions to choose from, try the `byobu-select-session` command.

The pts-2.mit session was the one I created initially without giving it a name, so the name was chosen by boybu.

If you want to find out which sessions are running, without attaching to any of them, use

```
byobu -ls
```

It drops you again at the console where you typed it after showing a list like:

```
There are screens on:
        17680.my-other-session  (03/12/2012 01:33:31 PM)        (Detached)
        11890.pts-2.mit         (01/15/2012 09:17:48 AM)        (Detached)
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```

Comment: For byobu with tmux I found these answers useful:  
http://askubuntu.com/questions/470208/use-multiple-byobu-sessions-while-ignoring-unrelated-tmux-sessions  
http://askubuntu.com/questions/196290/name-a-byobu-session

Answer (score 9):

Use the `-S` option to give your next byobu session (e.g. its socket) a different name. Without `-S "MYNAME"` the socket would be `<pid>.<tty>.<host>` instead of `<pid>.MYNAME`.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can work out, if you run `byobu` with no arguments then it reattaches to an existing session (or starts a new one if you aren't running `byobu` at all). If you run it with a program name as the argument then it will pass this to either `screen` or `tmux`, depending on what you are running inside.

If you're running `screen`, you can simulate starting a fresh session (executing your shell) by running `byobu byobu-shell` (`byobu-shell` being the program that `byobu` launches by defualt. It prints the MOTD and launches your `$shell`.). Then when you try to reattach, either by running `byobu` or reconnecting via SSH to the server, you'll be given a menu with options to choose between the running `byobu` sessions.

For `tmux`, execute `byobu new-session` to achieve this. The next time you reconnect you'll be attached to the last session you started.

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.  But running `byobu $shell` just reattaches to the already running session (this is because $shell is not defined/blank in the terminal). While running `byobu byobu-shell` just gives prints that byobu-shell is an unrecognised command. (Sorry if I have misunderstood what you said...)

Comment: What release are you running? `byobu-shell` is in Oneiric and newer. You can run `byobu bash` (or `zsh` or whatever) to get roughly the same effect.

Comment: I am running ubuntu 10.04, byobu version 5.2 and tmux 1.5. And, unfortunately, both `byobu bash` and `byobu zsh` given "unknown command" errors.  Is it perhaps something in my old `screen` set up? Any ideas?

Comment: I can't easily test Lucid I'm afraid, but if you're up for it you could install a newer version from the PPA: https://launchpad.net/~byobu/+archive/ppa/+packages

Comment: OK I reinstalled byobu using (byobu - 5.2-0ubuntu1~ppa2, the one for Lucid). `byobu -v` prints byobu version 5.2 and tmux 1.5 (same as earlier). But this has made no difference, `byobu` is still not recognising the second argument (bash, zsh etc).

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you were using `screen` for some reason. Reading from [the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/byobu.1.html), ("Options to `byobu` are simply passed through `screen(1)` or `tmux(1)`.") you might be able to do this with `new-session`, i.e. `byobu new-session`. I think that when reattaching in the `tmux` case, you'll be reattached to the most recently created session by default. I'm sorry that I can't test this for you at the minute; my internet has gone wonky. :(

Comment: Excellent. The command `byobu new-session` does exactly what I was looking for -- perhaps you can edit your answer or should I add another answer? Not quite sure of the protocol here! Many thanks for your help.

Comment: There we go, done. Glad we got there.

Comment: I'm still puzzled. I ssh to my Ubuntu server. It starts up screen/byobu, and presents me with something that looks like a curses-managed display (i.e. my terminal scrollbars are broken.) When I do the same thing from a second terminal, both terminals are looking at the same session. Typing "byobu new-session" resets the session in both terminals. I still only have one session, albeit two windows on to it.

Comment: The command I wanted was "byobu-disable", then reconnect as many times as you need. This isn't a solution to the precise OP, but it allows two different terminal sessions at once (without byobu), which is all I need.

Answer (score 2):

If you're connecting to a machine using ssh and you'd like to create a new byobu session, use:

```
ssh -t hostname byobu new-session
```

Note: The `-t` flag is needed to "Force pseudo-terminal allocation" otherwise you get the following error: "open terminal failed: not a terminal"

Once you have created the new session on a machine on any subsequent connection you'll be asked which byobu session you'd like to attach to.

Answer (score 1):

Or, when you are inside a byobu session already: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.

Comment: This appear to be incorrect as that key combination opens the Mondrian squares instead