# Name a Byobu session?

Tags: byobu, multiple-instances

Is there a way to create identifiable Byobu sessions so that when I've got multiple sessions running, the *byobu-select-session* menu gives me a list of sessions I can recognize, as opposed to non-descript tmux port numbers?

In an ideal world, it would be great to be able to both start a session giving it a name and to modify such a session to change a name if it's already running?  Is this possible, how?

**Edit 1:** Some further details:

- I'm using tmux as the backend and don't especially want to switch back to screen.
- I've now tried starting a session with `byobu -S "Name"` to no avail :-(

**Edit 2:** Some discoveries:

- I've now discovered a partial answer in using tmux native commands: `tmux rename-session <current-name> <new-name>` renames an existing session and `tmux new -s session_name` creates a new names session. I'm surprised `byobu -S "name"` isn't liked to `tmux new -s session_name` for byobu with a tmux backend.

Comment: have you tried: `byobu -S your-session-name`? See [how to run multiple byobu sessions at once?](http://askubuntu.com/a/112273/3712). I don't know whether it works if byobu uses tmux instead of screen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've now tried `byobu -S` to no avail. It appears to work with tmux as the backend... Is there anything similar for tmux?

Comment: `byobu new -s your-session-name` might work for tmux backend.

Comment: Your a star @J.F.Sebastian , that did the trick.  You can even rename a session using `byobu rename-session -t <original_name> <new_name>`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Your comment seems to be the correct answer - if you post that as answer and Ashimema accepts it then we all benefit from having another *answered* question.

Comment: @guntbert: I don't use tmux. It is better to post *tested* answers. It is OK to [ask and answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) i.e., Ashimema can post and accept his own answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Byobu is simply a shell for the tmux (or screen) back end terminal multiplexor. You can therefore pass any command that your back end supports through Byobu.

#### Byobu with *tmux* back end

*To start a new Byobu session with a specified name:*

```
byobu new -s <session-name>
```

*To change the name of a pre-existing session:*

```
byobu rename -t <session-name> <new-session-name>
```

#### Byobu with *screen* back end

*To start a new Byobu session with a specified name:*

```
byobu -S <session-name>
```

*To change the name of a pre-existing session:*

```
byobu -X <session-name> <new-session-name>
```

**Note:** All credit to J.F.Sabastian for his help. I've now verified the above commands are correct for both Tmux and Screen backed Byobu.

Comment: This works with tmux but not gnu screen